# JSF acessando porta serial

Tags: java, jsf, serial

Estou trabalhando num sistema em JSF e preciso enviar dados para a porta serial do cliente (impressora).

O único caminho é mesmo usando Applets?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nisso: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml Eu já vi aplicativos distribuidos assim funcionando muito bem. Uma página do seu sistema web disponibilizaria um sistema Java desktop através de um link, e este sistema Java é quem faria a festa. Funciona bem com os principais navegadores e com o IE é transparente, você clica e o aplicativo já sai executando - é lógico que na primeia vez e também a cada atualização o usuário é requisitado a permitir que o aplicativo seja executado em sua máquina.

Answer (score 1):

Se você precisa de acesso de baixo nível (i.e., fazer mais do que ativar a janela de impressão do navegador com JavaScript) você vai precisar de algo no cliente sim, porém eu não recomendaria um Applet. Após tantos anos o futuro dos Applets está um tanto quanto incerto. O pessoal do Chrome está [descontinuando o suporte a NPAPI](http://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation); outros navegadores também estão pouco a pouco dificultando a execução de Applets. Até onde vai meu conhecimento a Oracle ainda não se pronunciou sobre o assunto (além de [recomendar](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml) que usuários procurem outros navegadores).

Hoje eu não vejo muitas alternativas no mundo do Java. Você pode distribuir uma Aplicação *desktop* para os seus clientes (e.g., compartilhar um `jar`, ou até mesmo se valer do [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javawebstart/index.html) - enquanto ele ainda for suportado).

Mas isso fica claramente em uma camada separada da sua aplicação JSF. Para acessá-la você precisaria de algum mecanismo de integração (e.g., Web Services ou uma página de controle local).

---

#### Algumas perguntas interessantes no SOEn:

1. [How can a web page read from the user's serial port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171522/how-can-a-web-page-read-from-the-users-serial-port)
2. [Javascript interface with RS-232 Serial Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592099/javascript-interface-with-rs-232-serial-port)

Comment: Cheguei a pensar em criar um app desktop para isso, mas o problema é que a requisição deveria partir da aplicação web para a aplicação desktop, e isso (acho) não dá pra fazer. Ou dá?

Comment: Dá. Você pode, por exemplo, levantar um servidor http embarcado na sua aplicação "desktop" e expor alguns web-services, ou até uma página local. Sua página web principal chamaria esses web services locais ou faria um post para essa página local.